# DataTable OnRowChanged event raises twice?

Tags: c#, events, datatable

I want to listen to an RowChanged event while filling data with a SqlDataAdapter. It works but the event raised twice in spite of the fact that data do not change. Can somebody explain me why? What can I do to raise only once?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "myConnectionString";

        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(OnDataTableRowChanged);

        using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from TableX", sqlCon);

            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }

        dataTable.RowChanged -= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(OnDataTableRowChanged);
    }

    static void OnDataTableRowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var table = (DataTable)sender;

        Console.WriteLine("line: " + e.Row[0] + ", RowCount: " + table.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will fire twice once for ADD once for COMMIT.

Check e.Action it will give you the Action for which it was fired